Suggested Mesh Count for this Image?
I'm new to screen printing and am trying to determine the best screen mesh count for this image:

Thanks in advance.

I think this is just opinion-based, and can be closed as such, but, to be sure: what exactly do you want the result to look like? What have you tried so far? What are your concerns?

How are you planning on half toning it? What inks are you using? Those are the two main things will determine the mesh count. Thinner inks (like black) and finer details call for finer meshes. You will not be able to print it as is, either halftone or looks like 3-4 ink colors depending how you want the shading done.

@Joachim.  This is my first attempt at screen printing so any recommendations including modifying or simplifying the artwork are welcome.

@rebusB. I bought a Speedball screenprinting kit which contains water-based inks. This is my first attempt at screenprinting so any recommendations are welcome.  I can also simplify the artwork and elimate the grayscale making it just black and white if needed

Looks like the kits come with a 110 mesh screen which should be good for what you are doing. Could probably go finer but start with what you have. At this point unless you are going very coarse or very fine you should be good. There are different ways of making the resist to try too, your kit should have a guide that makes suggestions if not Speedball has it on their website.

Multiply the dots/lines per inch of the image by four (or five if you want even more detail). There are other factors though so this is a general rule. That is also targeting halftone images in order to capture the smallest halftone dots. Graphic designs (not photographs) can go with lower resolution meshes.
Mesh count in this case is the screen fabric thread count per inch. Basically you want the lowest mesh number that gives you the best details for the image (does not appear blurry when printed) and leaves the right amount of ink on the surface. That will vary with the inks used and the material you are printing on.
Looking at the image above, it reports in at 72 pixels per inch (that is screen resolution so your original may be higher res) and 547x640 pixels. That is 7.76" x 8.88" print size. So by that measure it would call for a screen of 288. That would probably be overkill on this design though. Chances are you would print it larger, lowering the DPI, and does not have much in the way of fine details.
Here are some general guidelines:

30 to 61 Mesh Count Screens: high density and glitter inks
80 to 86 Mesh Count Screens: metallic inks, athletic wear, and heavy inks (like plastisol white)
110 to 135 Mesh Count: standard mesh count, good for text to spot colors. Recommended for basic printing.
156 Mesh Count: standard for higher quality images and text.
196 Mesh Count: finer details, less ink deposit, good for small text like neck tags. (~180 was the highest we would use on t-shirts for with black plastisol inks)
230 Mesh Count: this and higher used for photoreal halftones
305 Mesh Count: very fine mesh, for limited ink deposit and extremely fine details.
(source)

